# Location of propel.ini for symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I am migrating from symfony1 to symfony2, I have hard time implementing propel behaviors. Where do I actually have the propel.ini in symfony2?

Well in sf1.4, it was inside root config directory. How about symfony2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Propel ORM Symfony2 page](http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/working-with-symfony2.html#propel_configuration) says this:

> You can add a app/config/propel.ini file in your project to specify some configuration parameters. ... However, the recommended way to configure Propel is to rely on build properties.
>
> You can define build properties by creating a propel.ini file in app/config like below, but you can also follow the Symfony2 convention by adding build properties in app/config/config.yml

So I believe you can come close to the Symfony1 behaviour by creating `app/config/propel.ini`, but the more idiomatic way is to use `app/config/config.yml` as that page illustrates.

Caveat: I haven't used Propel with Symfony2, so this answer is solely based on the manual.

Comment: Thank you. That helped but I used propel.ini and used import in config.yml.